# Laravel Unable to Detect Application Environment

Tags: php, laravel, configuration, frameworks

I have three environment folders in the config directory in Laravel: development, testing, and local. When I change the environment and hostname within the start.php file, only the production environment is recognized. Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong here?

app/routes.php

```
//using this as a test to confirm that the correct environment is being used

Route::get('/', function()
{
   var_dump(App::environment());
});
```

bootstrap/start.php:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(

'development' => array('localhost'),

));
```

Here, the result should be "string(11) "development". Instead, it's "string(10) "production".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`localhost` probably isn't the real hostname of your machine.
You can find out your hostname by echoing `gethostname()`. Then use that instead of `localhost`

Comment: Thank you, you were right. Apparently, the real hostname of my machine is "My-Computer.local." Problem solved.

Comment: Just to add to this answer, if on a Mac using terminal, or Windows using command prompt, you can simply write "hostname" and it will give you the hostname :)

Comment: @Karl Good tip. I'll stick with the `gethostname()` in the answer because its cross-platform and it's certain that it returns what Laravel wants (because it uses the same function internally)